# Convert Fixed Value to Floating Value in SPSS

Tags: fixed, spss, floating

I have data in '0' and '1' form in my SPSS data file, but according to my client's need I have to convert it in the form '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11'.
Is there any way to do so in SPSS? If there is, please do let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Nikhil, is it that you have a variable like region which is stored as multiple dichotomous variables, where as you/your client requires a single categorical variable instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming @Jinesh Sutar is correct in the above comment, to change your multiple variables into a single categorical variable you can use the following syntax. `varx` and `newvar` would obviously need renamed for your dataset.

```
IF (var1=1) newvar=1.
IF (var2=1) newvar=2.
IF (var3=1) newvar=3.
IF (var4=1) newvar=4.
IF (var5=1) newvar=5.
IF (var6=1) newvar=6.
IF (var7=1) newvar=7.
IF (var8=1) newvar=8.
IF (var9=1) newvar=9.
IF (var10=1) newvar=10.
IF (var11=1) newvar=11.
EXECUTE.
```

Answer (score 0):

Nikhil, if I am correct, the data you must be having is in **checked/ unchecked** form. You need to convert it into **Item numbers per column**. This can be done using vectors in SPSS:

```
vector multin = var1 to var11.
loop #i=1 to 11.
if (multin(#i)=1) multin(#i)=#i.
end loop.
exe.
```

Using this, there is no need to create a new variable(newvar).